# I can’t get the complete HTML source of a web page

Tags: html, ruby, browser, nokogiri

I want to code a `crawler` program with `Ruby` and `Nokogiri`. 
My goal website URL is `apk.hiapk.com/search?pid=0&key=%E5%8A%A9%E6%89%8B&pi=3`

It's search URL is `http://apk.hiapk.com/searchpid=0&key=%E5%8A%A9%E6%89%8B&pi=3`.

When I try this code:

```
url = URI.encode("http://apk.hiapk.com/search?pid=0&key=#{key}&pi=#{page}" )

content = client.get_content(url)

html_doc = Nokogiri::HTML(content)
```

I will get this page’s `HTML`, but the `HTML` is not the complete source, it has some `HTML` elements missing.

When I use Firefox and visit this URL, then I can get the complete HTML source. I want to know what happened, and why. What technology is used in this website?

Comment: I can't get a complete web page html source.

Comment: Maybe there is JavaScript code that creates new elements. Crawlers generally don’t execute scripts.

Comment: why dont you just use `Nokogiri::HTTP(url)` it will give you everything.

Comment: By digging into the page itself you could have figured out what technology is being used. `curl`, `wget` or `nokogiri` at the command-line will retrieve the page just as a HTTP client would, making it easy for you to look. If a page uses JavaScript to load elements or sections then you have to use Watir or similar tools to retrieve the information. Your question was premature; There are a number of pages on SO about scraping in Ruby where content is missing, so a search would have got you started.

Answer (score 0):

When I use

```
Nokogiri::HTML(open("http://apk.hiapk.com/search?pid=0&key=%E5%8A%A9%E6%89%8B&pi=10"))
```

it is successful, and I get the complete HTML source.

So now I known what the reason is.

Comment: this problem is what I make . my code is not right, so i can't get complete HTML source.